# Fuel Tank Capacity

Tags: honda, fuel-tank, bajaj, hero-honda

I have a Pulsar 150 2016 model motorcycle. Recently I started filling full tank fuel in my motorcycle.

Yesterday I filled 17.4 litres of fuel with around 1 litre already in tank.
My bike took 18.5 litres to fill the tank.

But according to Bajaj, tank capacity is 15L. nI also Checked in Bunk with 5Litre Jar.

Can someone please help me understand this difference in fuel capacity.

Comment: What you mean by "Checked in Bunk with 5Litre Jar" is unclear. What does "checked in Bunk" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair.
This is very much possible because the Actual capacity of a vehicle may be different from the indicated by the manufacture.
Fuel tank capacity mentioned by the car manufacturer is just a "safe filling limit" and not the actual capacity of the tank.
This new might be helpful

https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/mangaluru/51-litres-of-diesel-in-a-42-litre-car-tank-its-possible/articleshow/64359342.cms

Comment: i think the 15litres is where the low fuel light turns on but you will still have 3,5 litres of reserve capacity in your tank.

Comment: I have gotten accurate measure of a couple car fuel tanks and they have been 5 to 10 % greater than  manual listing.